# Toshiba satellite L850 key for BIOS

Tags: bios, fn-key, toshiba-laptop

I cant get in BIOS to my Toshiba laptop. Probably I turned on the fast boot or because of <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

How can I get in bios BIOS?

Comment: The BIOS key is F2. - Spam this whilst booting up your computer or if you see the Toshiba logo start to press it then.

Comment: I tried but it does not work now... does it have to do with fn key ?

Answer (score 1):

The Toshiba Hardware utility (HWSetup) can also be used to change some of the settings if F2 or F12 does not work. This method may be the only way to access the BIOS settings on some laptops.
Select the Start button.
In the search, type in "HWSetup."
In the search returns select HW Setup to open.
Make changes as necessary and select "Apply."
Reboot the computer if not prompted to do so.
If not already installed, the Toshiba Hardware utility can be downloaded from http://support.toshiba.com after clicking "Downloads" and selecting your computer information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have FAST boost enabled, in my experience it is almost impossible to get into the BIOS (F2). Try searching/opening "Toshiba System Settings" (if applicable) and change FAST boost back to NORMAL (this can also be changed in the BIOS, if only you could get to it).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reset your BIOS.

**Method 1**: Remove the power source (cable and battery), and hold-press power button for 1 minute. Reinstall the battery and try to boot in BIOS now.

**Method 2**: Remove all power source (cables, battery, and CMOS battery also). CMOS battery holds the setting memory even after shutdown. Removing it will reset the setting.

Answer (score 0):

I just had success with holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then pressing the power button.

This was on an L855-14Q.