# cannot start BIOS instead grub o.4.4 menu appears. im trying to boot pop!_os from a USB, any ideas?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, grub

am i pressing the wrong key to start BIOS ive tried all f1,f2 etc?

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Home Basic
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Manufacturer TOSHIBA
System Model    Satellite L850-B184
System Type x64-based PC
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2501 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Insyde Corp. 1.40, 4/24/2012
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
```

Comment: You need to use the key mentioned on your user's manual, not guess. And the installation media must support booting in the required mode (UEFI or Legacy/BIOS).

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes it is f2 i tried it but it leads to windows boot manager

Comment: ive watched tutorials and ive seen the iso boot from BIOS so.. its supported

Comment: How exactly have you made the USB media? The last comment suggests you just copied the ISO...

Comment: i burnt it to a usb using balena etcher

Comment: but thats not the point. i cant open BIOS

Comment: a red screen with grub 0.4.4 menu shows up\

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/669275/toshiba-satellite-l850-key-for-bios

Comment: when i use the HW utility its says toshiba machine not detected, is it because im using a dell monitor connected to the toshiba laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm i fixed it somehow by using easybcd to write the boot manager to mbr which somehow erased the legacy grub menu that was opening then i resetted the CMOS battery and tada! my toshiba logo started appearing again and i disabled fast boot through the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You were pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> after your manufacturing PC's logo went, so you were taken to the Windows Boot Manager or the GRUB. Try pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> a couple of times just when you start the PC or the manufacturer's logo comes.